# How to execute an included/required PHP file without having to make calls to it's functions or use auto_prepend_file ?

Tags: php

This might be a total NOOB question but I am having difficulty including and executing a file. I understand I can require_once('file.php') but then I am going to have to manually call the functions within this file instead of having the file run by itself (it's procedural in nature).

I can use php_value auto_prepend_file 'file.php' in my .htaccess or apache conf folder, but it already has auto prepended files which I cannot remove.

Can anyone suggest something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a require_once and you put your code in the body of the required document it will be executed when you do the require_once.

If you have your code in functions then you can call them in the required document:

```
<?php

    function DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something :D
    }

    DoSomething();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

somefile.php:

```
<?php

   include('somefile.txt');
```

somefile.txt:

```
hello, <?php echo 'world!'; ?>
```

Then at your shell prompt (or via web browser):

```
$ php somefile.php
hello, world!
```

Nothing need to be done. If you `include` or `require` a file, it's parsed and any `<?php ... ?>` code blocks are executed. If you have "executable" code that's not buried inside a `function(...) { .... }` definition, it'll be executed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `file.php` that looks something like:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

PHP will automatically parse and execute the file. For instance, all I would have to do in `index.php` is

```
<?php
include 'file.php';
?>
```

Comment: so include also executes the file ? I was under the impression that it would not do so.

Comment: @ParijatKalia Try it for yourself! That's the best way to figure this stuff out.

Comment: Thanks all, I gave the guy with the least points @Gusman the correct answer. Hopefully you guys won't mind that :)